# Android Image Invalid File Name Error

Tags: android, image, layout

I am simply trying to add an image to my android activity but I get the following error:

```
res\drawable-hdpi\restLogo.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

As you can see the error makes no sense, at least to me. The file name contains only a-z 0-9_. Agh Why am I getting this error?

Here is what is in the layout file:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Logo" 
    style=""
    android:src="@drawable/restLogo" />
```

I thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `restlogo.png` or `rest_logo.png`. When they say `a-z`, they literally mean only the lowercase `a-z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
res\drawable-hdpi\restLogo.png:
```

Image name should be in lowercase , so change it to restlogo.png or whatever but in lowercase